# Why do I get a 502 when I visit my mobile services URL?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I've got a Azure Mobile Service that has been working for a while in production. I'm using it for logging crashes / errors from my Win8 app.

The URL for the service is :
https://silveroakapps-allaboutmoney.azure-mobile.net/

When I hit that URL in a browser, I used to get a generic page that comes up for all Azure Mobile Services. But today, I've been getting a 502.

To test if there's anything wrong with my mobile service or Azure account, I created another service - https://all-about-money.azure-mobile.net/ , which seems to be working ok.

Any ideas, what's going wrong and what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an outage was affecting some sites; the issue should have been resolved at this point.